# Square brackets indexing a Perl list literal

Tags: perl, syntax

Consider:

```
my($a, $b) = (1,2,3,4)[0,3];
print $a . ' ' . $b;
```

I understand that it will print `1 4` but I can't find documentation about this feature. What is it actually doing?

Answer (score 4):

This is called array or list [*slicing*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

> A slice accesses several elements of a list, an array, or a hash simultaneously using a list of subscripts. It's more convenient than writing out the individual elements as a list of separate scalar values.

Comment: The OP's code is specifically a list slice (`(LIST)[LIST]`) and not an array slice (`@NAME[LIST]`, `@$NAME[LIST]` or `@BLOCK[LIST]`).

Comment: yes, this is a list slice, not an array slice; the two work very differently when there is no element at one or more of the indexes